Clean Architecture: How to register DbContext if my Data Access layer is a "detail"
I am implementing a project using Clean Architecture in .NET 7. As per the Clean Architecture diagram below, we should not reference the Data Access project directly, and only through an interface.
So how can I register the Data Access layer's dependencies without violating the Clean Architecture principle?
If I call builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext>() method in Program.cs then I have to add a reference of the DataAccess library, which is violating the Clean Architecture's principles.


use DI and register like services.AddDbContext<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(...));services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>();

You can expose a single service instance via multiple interfaces with a factory method; services.AddScoped<TInterface>(sp => sp.GetService<IMyDbContext>())

You should use the interface to inject the service instead of directly using the dataaccessor's dbcontext.

@BrandoZhang When I try to use an interface instead of the concrete type, I get an error message: The type IApplicationDbContext cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method AddDbContext(IServiceCollection, Action?, ServiceLifetime....

@JeremyLakeman is services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetService()) the same as services.AddDbContext()? Doesn't AddDbContext do additional logic?

.AddDbContext<>() adds all of the EF services to the provider, including your context. .AddDbContext<,>() lets you hide your context behind a single interface. You can then create an alias to your context instance by the above. So you can split your schema into different interfaces if you wish to limit visibility.

In order not to violate the Clean Architecture principle by calling your DBcontext directly in your Program.cs you can achieve that through abstraction. First create a class with a static IServiceCollection  method in your Data Access Layer and register your application DbContext. Then  call the Registration method in your Program.cs
  public static class DataAccessServiceReg
  {
    public static IServiceCollection AddDataAccessServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Services.AddDbContext<DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext>();


        return services;
    }
}

In Your Program.Cs can now register the  data access service defined in the data access layer
builder.Services.AddDataAccessServices(builder.Configuration);

With this setup separation of concerns required by clean Architecture is maintained and you main application wont reference your DBContext directly.
You can look at this public template on  Clean Architecture where I  implemented this  here
I hope this helps.

thank you for your feedback, but if AddDataAccessServices is a method in the Data Access layer, you still need to reference that Library from Program.cs.
